# Difference in use openCV ios9 ios8

Tags: opencv, ios7, ios8, ios9

In my app I'm using openCV 2.4.9, I have a template which i match with another image by using

```
cvMatchShapes(seq0, seqT, CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1)
```

and the problem that on ios8 and ios9 this command returns different values

Comment: i think you should use the latest version of opencv i.e. 3.0 to work well with iOS 9.

Comment: thanks for advice, already done, works well